# How to exclude N/A while calculating daily log returns

Tags: log-returns

I have daily price data of hundreds of companies from 2010-01-01 to 2020-08-21, there are many missing values in my data frame. if I use na.omit, it deletes all my data. I try to use ROC(), but it does not work due to NA values.

How can I exclude N/A and calculate daily log returns?

Thank you guy, I know you are genius

Comment: which program language are you asking for

Comment: Hi, I am using R to get the returns.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions possible, depending on the situation.

What CRSP does is something like this:

If the price is "missing" on day t, you compute the return for day t as also "missing"

else if the price on day t exists, compute the return for today as the return from the *most recent available price* (which may not be $P_{t-1}$ if $P_{t-1}$ is missing) to the current i.e day t price. Store this value in a dataframe. Optionally you can also store a "return_days" counter which tracks the number of days for the return (1 when there is no missing data, in general $N$ where the return you computed is $\log(P_t/P_{t-N})$ because you skipped over $N-1$ missing days).

Like all programming techniques this solution of course has advantages and disadvantages.